# VUE using State Axios data in Component with another Axios function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a Vue State: (components.js)

```
const actions = {
  [DCOMPONENTS] (context) {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
      ESApiService.get ("/ api / components")
        .then (({data}) => {
          context.commit (SET_COMPONENTS, data.data.data);
          //context.commit(SET_USER_ACCOUNT, payload);
          resolve (data);
        })
        .catch (({response}) => {
          context.commit (SET_ERROR, response);
        });
    });
  },
};
```

This is executed immediately if you are logged in to the application. I then want to use this data in the SalesTable.vue component.

This is also going well. In the SalesTable.vue I use a new Axios call to get another data set that I don't need to store in STATE.

```
 methods: {
         async loadTable () {
         await this. $ store
          .dispatch (SALES)
            let tableName = 'SalesTable';
            var components = this.getComponents;
            var sales = this.getSales;
            var i;
          
            for (i = 0; i <components.length; i ++) {
              if (components [i] .name == tableName) {
                var structure = components [i];
              }
            }

            var jsonData = {};
            jsonData.structure = structure;
            jsonData.data = sales;
            this.structureTable = jsonData;
            this.dynamicComponent = Tables;
      },
```

The problem: It sometimes happens that components.js Promise is later than the 2nd Axios call within SalesTable.vue. This means the data set (this.structureTable = jsonData) isn't fully loaded with the STATE data and my table won't generate.

Comment: `ESApiService.get()` already appears to return a promise. There's no need to wrap it in a new one

Comment: _"`this. $ store`"_  what's up with all the syntax-breaking spaces?

Comment: @Phil sorry, that is a mistake. It is: this.$store ofcourse. The problem is that when I call function loadTable in the SalesTable.vue, sometimes the Axios call which happens in the state isn't ready yet. I want to make sure that the Axios call (state has been set) is fully done, before function LoadTable is being fired.